# Where to set advanced settings for serial port on linux

Tags: linux, usb, serial-port, com

I use a special USB to serial adapter to get data from legacy hardware.
Under Windows i have to set some advanced settings in order to start sending data in a way the devices can "understand" and "talk" me back.
Where in linux can I modify these settings?
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS/Win 7 64-bit and I know this adapter is accessible in /dev/ttyUSB0
I can even read data coming from the device but I need to properly set those attributes so the communication can continue without problems.
[image]

Comment: You should have some number of  /dev/ttyS#  ---run ls /dev to find out how many and slave traffic to one that is free like in windows

Answer (score 0):

Use **minicom**. Install it by typing `sudo apt-get install minicom`. Then run `minicom -s` and configure your serial port settings in the *Serial Port* menu. Then select *Save setup as dfl*. Exit, and then run minicom. If it gives you error that you don't have permissions, try `sudo minicom`. Now it is the same as Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The `stty` command can be used to change the parameters of a serial port in Linux, such as baud rate, number of start, stop and parity bits, and flow control options, among others.

You can find [some documentation on it](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Serial-HOWTO/#stty_) in the [Serial HOWTO on TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Serial-HOWTO/).